# SSRS: Dynamic SQL vs Dynamic Data Source (Connection String) when using stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to decide on a standard for SSRS reports that must be run against multiple databases.

For the purposes of this question we will assume:

- all databases are on the same server
- must support stored procedures as data sources

As I see it there are advantages and disadvantages to each approach, a few that come to mind (there are likely others I'm overlooking):

Dynamic SQL advantages:
- stored procedure only needs to be deployed to only one database(reduces "clutter"
- only one definition to maintain/deploy

Dynamic Data Source (connection) advantages:
- Proper compile time checking
- easier detection of dependencies during schema changes
- easier consumption from alternative (non-SSSRS) applications

In my opinion the Dynamic Data Source approach is somewhat better (assuming one has some automated way of deploying definitions across all servers to ensure consistency) but in case someone argues against that I'd like to be as informed as possible as to the merits of each approach.